# How to get the matrix output from the function?

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to figure out how to use this function but cannot seem to get the `x` input to do anything. Whenever I input number value for `x` it tells me that it can't work because of a 'size' issue.

What should I do?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import diags, kron, identity
from scipy.sparse.linalg import inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def laplacian_1D(x):
    """Construct the 1D Laplacian matrix on the domain defined by x. Note that
    we assume a constant spacing.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array-like, shape (nx, )
        One dimensional mesh.

    Returns
    -------
    A : scipy sparse matrix, shape (nx, nx)
        Laplacian matrix.

    """

    # -->
    n = x.size
    # -->
    dx = x[1]-x[0]

    # -->
    d2 = [np.ones(n-1), -2*np.ones(n), np.ones(n-1)]

    # -->
    A = diags(d2, [-1, 0, 1]) / dx**2

    return A


print(laplacian_1D(10))
```

The error reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/PycharmProjects/ENSAM/Math/Exercise_1.py", line 52, in <module>
    print(laplacian_1D(10))
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/PycharmProjects/ENSAM/Math/Exercise_1.py", line 23, in laplacian_1D
    n = x.size
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: Most notably, the function documentation clearly specifies the required input shape.  Calling it with a "number value" is invalid input.

Comment: I added the error that I have @Prune

Comment: I don't understand what it means by input shape :/

Comment: If you search in your browser for "NumPy shape", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: You need to input a 1d numpy array, not an integer.

Comment: @Heike Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the parameter description the function expects to get an numpy array or a list as an argument. For example calling `laplacian_1D(x = np.arange(10))` will return a laplacian matrix of shape (10,10). Note that the only way how x is used in the function is for determining the size of the output matrix and the dx-value. The latter tells you that the x should be a list with increasing values of its elements.

Comment: This is my first timing learning how to use a function like this so I appreciate the help. I know the question was a little stupid. Thank you!

Comment: Assigning a value to an argument like that in a function call, i.e. `x = np.arange(10)`, is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: I don't agree with you. It may not be in accordance with some style norm, but it runs reliably. Therefore, it seems to me to be valid.  Secondly, for functions with many arguments it is very helpful to have it that way. I also think that this was the best didactic way to give the questioner an idea of what is going on. Maybe you were referring to the default values in a function definition that aren't supposed to be a function themselves?